# Date input validation against database in Laravel

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-4

This is what I have, it is just storing the values multiple times even though I have a rules to check the uniqueness against "appointments" table in the database. 
Can anyone suggest me how I can store only unique date in my table. Thanks in advance.

```
    public function store()
        {
            date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Melbourne');
            $date = date('Y/m/d', time());
            $todDate = new DateTime($date);
            $dateFormated = $todDate->format('Y-m-d');

        $input = Input::all();

        $rules = array(
            'appoint_day' => 'required|unique:appointments'
        );

        $validator = Validator::make($input, $rules);

        if($validator->passes())
        {
            $schedule = new Appointment;
            $appoint_day = Input::get('appoint_date');

            if(strtotime($appoint_day) - strtotime($dateFormated) >= 0)
            {
                $schedule->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
                $schedule->appoint_day = $appoint_day;
                $schedule->save();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'failed';

        }
 return View::make('admin.professions.appointments');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Input` value is named `appoint_date`, but you are validating a field called `appoint_day`, which presumably does not exist. Change your field name to `appoint_day` and the validator should function correctly.

Comment: Wow! Quite Strange! appoint_day is a column name in table where is appoint_date is a input field name. Yes, your solution worked but I didn't understand the reason behind it. Thank You so much!!.

Comment: It's because the validator expects the name of the *fields* to check (which is in the `Input` array), but you have no `appoint_day` field...so it's not validating anything. Also, the `unique` rule checks the database using the input field name as he column name, unless you specify otherwise. So if you kept your field name as `appoint_date`, you could alternatively do `'appoint_date' => 'required|unique:appointments,appoint_day'`.

Comment: A quick help please related with the above question:
How can I validate unique "appoint_date" with unique users ?
Means, the same date like 01/01/2010 is unique for User1 also User 2!
How about the following: 
$rules = array(
            'appoint_day' => 'required|unique:appointments, user_id'
        );

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you're trying to accomplish; the code you suggest would check if `appoint_day` was unique among the field `user_id`. More info about your intentions is needed...I suggest you post a new question with full details.